# How to Replace Words Outside Of Quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to replace strings outside of quotes using str.replaceAll in Java but to leave words inside quotes untouched

If I replaced Apple with Pie:

Input: Apple "Apple Apple Apple"
Desired Output: Pie "Apple Apple Apple"

Note the words inside quotes were untouched

How would this be done? All help Appreciated!

Comment: Why are there parens in your example?  Will there always be parens around the quotes?

Comment: No, there will not always be parenthens around quotes

Comment: @freakshow1217 so you want to change only the first occurrence of the word?

Comment: All occurences of the word, if possible

Comment: then wouldnt apple in the quotes also be replaced?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to fix, I don't want words inside the quotes to be touched

Comment: Will this ever have more complicated examples, e.g. Apple "Apple and Banana", which should get changed to Pie "Apple and Banana"? If so, then regex will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for `Apple` using lookaheads to make sure it is not surrounded by quotes:

```
(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)Apple
```

And replace by:

```
Pie
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO5aO6/1)

---

**Update:**

Based on comments below you can use:

**Code:**

```
String str = "Apple \"Apple\"";
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)Apple", "Pie");
//=> Pie "Apple" "Another Apple Apple Apple" Pie
```

Comment: This would have the (possibly desired) side effect of changing "CrabApple" to "CrabPie", would it not?

Comment: I have a problem: I want it so that even if it isn't touching a quote, it will not get replaced: "Apple Apple Apple" Results in -> "Apple Pie Apple"

Comment: Hmm that will complicate regex to a great extent, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want:

```
String str = "Apple \"Apple\"";
String replace = str.replaceAll("(?<!\")Apple(?!\")", "Pie");
```

Here is the working:https://regex101.com/r/kP0oV1/2

Comment: How would I use this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for your test:

```
package mavensandbox;


import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;

public class Test {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        String input = "Apple(\"Apple\")";
        String output = replaceThoseWithoutQuotes("Apple", "Pie", input);
        assertEquals("Pie(\"Apple\")", output);
    }

    private String replaceThoseWithoutQuotes(String replace, String with, String input) {
        return input.replaceAll("(?<!\")" + replace + "(?!\")", with);
    }
}
```

I'm using what's called a [negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  It finds matches that don't have a " in front or behind of it.  Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try matching the word with whitespace after it.

/Apple\s/

Then replace with Pie with the same whitespace after it.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an option to do this without a more complicated regex if you're looking for a more iterative solution, if you're so inclined. You can split on `"` and replace even-numbered indexes and then rebuild the string.

```
    String input = "\"unique\" unique unique \"unique\" \"unique\" \"unique\" \"unique\" unique \"unique unique\" unique unique \"";
    System.out.println(input);
    String[] split = input.split("\"");
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i = i + 2) {
        split[i] = split[i].replaceAll("unique", "potato");
    }
    String output = "";
    for (String s : split) {
        output += s + "\"";
    }
    System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

```
"unique" unique unique "unique" "unique" "unique" "unique" unique "unique unique" unique unique "
"unique" potato potato "unique" "unique" "unique" "unique" potato "unique unique" potato potato "
```